# Get Document out of Array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called season that looks like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    week: 1,
    matchups: [ 
        {
            home : ObjectId("1"),
            away : ObjectId("2")
        },
        {
            home : ObjectId("3"),
            away : ObjectId("4")
        },

    ],
    _id: 50fc50c9ce87149ee3000007 
  },
  { 
    week: 2,
    matchups: [ 
        {
            home : ObjectId("3"),
            away : ObjectId("1")
        },
        {
            home : ObjectId("2"),
            away : ObjectId("4")
        },
    ],
    _id: 50fc50c9ce87149ee3000008 
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get all of the matchups where the home OR away team is ObjectId("1"). I want the return to look like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    week: 1,
    matchups: [ 
        {
            home : ObjectId("1"),
            away : ObjectId("2")
        }

    ],
    _id: 50fc50c9ce87149ee3000007 
  },
  { 
    week: 2,
    matchups: [ 
        {
            home : ObjectId("3"),
            away : ObjectId("1")
        }
    ],
    _id: 50fc50c9ce87149ee3000008 
  }
]
```

Is it possible to get this result using on db.season.find()?

Comment: I know that ObjectId("1") isn't valid. I was just trying to keep things short and sweet. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have at most one potential `matchups` element to match, you can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator to do this:

```js
db.seasons.find(
    {$or: [{'matchups.home': ObjectId("1")},{'matchups.away': ObjectId("1")}]}, 
    {week: 1, matchups: {
        $elemMatch: {$or: [{home: ObjectId("1")},{away: ObjectId("1")}]}
    }});
```

Same caveat as Wes regarding the invalidity of `ObjectId("1")`.

Comment: Wow, that's a nice addition--new in 2.2. Guess I haven't been playing with 2.2 enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not with .find, but with .aggregate:

```
db.seasons.aggregate(
  {$match:{$or:[{"matchups.home":ObjectId("1")}, {"matchups.away":ObjectId("1")}]}}, 
  {$unwind:"$matchups"}, 
  {$match:{$or:[{"matchups.home":ObjectId("1")}, {"matchups.away":ObjectId("1")}]}}, 
  {$group:{_id:"$_id", week:{$first:"$week"}, matchups:{$addToSet:"$matchups"}}});
```

1. first match filters on the ones that have your team (will make the rest more efficient if there are some records that don't contain your team)
2. unwind breaks out the matchups
3. second match filters on only the ones that have your team
4. group rebuilds your records again

Limitations are the document size with aggregate. Hope this helps.

The best you can do with .find is the first match, and then filter the matchups on the application side, AFAIK.

Also, ObjectId("1") is invalid, FYI.

Comment: I'll leave my answer here just to show how annoying it would have been without the $elemMatch projection, haha.

Comment: I also like this solution because when you group things back together, it gives me the home team and the way team rather than just a matchup id.